# Microsoft.usage warning when there's two nested using clauses

Tags: c#

I'm wondering why does Visual Studio code analysis give a warning with this little bit of code:

```
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes("myImage.png");
using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data))
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(mem))            
{
     // do something with the bitmap
}
```

The error is:

> Object 'mem' can be disposed more than once in method ... To avoid
>   generating a System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call
>   Dispose more than one time on an object.

And how to correct this? (Yes, I could load bitmap directly from file, but in my real project I have my own file format where multiple images are saved into one file and therefore I need a `MemoryStream` to load the data from a specific range in the file)

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but "If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one. The object must not throw an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times." [(source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with regards to the second reliability warning, it seems like when this situation occurs, code analysis will complain with either CA2000 *or* CA2202 regardless of what you do. There's multiple complaints about this, [here's one for your enjoyment.](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/611525/disposable-objects-and-ca2000-ca2202-warnings)

Just to see if it's particular to using syntax, I expanded out the using into a try catch block and you get the same behavior.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] data = {};
            //using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(data)))
            //{ }

            MemoryStream mem = null;
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try
            {
                mem = new MemoryStream(data);
                bitmap = new Bitmap(mem);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (null!= bitmap ) bitmap.Dispose();                
                // commenting this out will provoke a CA2000.
                // uncommenting this will provoke CA2202.
                // so pick your poison.
                // if (null != mem) mem.Dispose();
            }
        } 
    }
```

edit: There is, as you (Jaska) pointed out, a note from Microsoft about flagging intent about the memorystream in the Bitmap's using block:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1000];
            MemoryStream mem = null;
            try
            {
                mem = new MemoryStream(data);
                using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(mem))
                {
                    mem = null; // <-- this line will make both warning go away
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (mem != null)
                {
                    mem.Dispose();
                }
            } 
        } 
    }
```

I'm glad to see that this works, but at the same time it's a bit uglier than using an anonymous memorystream in the bitmap's constructor. Ah well.

Comment: yes i tried almost exactly the same code and got same findings. This one must just be ignored or suppressed :(

Comment: Your answer led me to the solution to get rid of both! solution is to set memory stream to null inside the using -statement. For ur info also @John-Skeet i'll post an answer in a minute

Comment: Because your provided link led me to the solution, if you want me to accept your answer please refine it as in my own answer and i'll accept yours.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `Bitmap` takes ownership of the stream it's given in its constructor. *It* will dispose of the stream - you don't need to. So all you need is:

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(data)))            
{
     // do something with the bitmap
}
```

Comment: Your code generates another warning: Microsoft.Reliability : In method --- object 'new MemoryStream(data)' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'new MemoryStream(data)' before all references to it are out of scope.

Comment: @Jon - And `MemoryStream.Dispose()` is a dummy anyway. But I'd still rather have the `using (MemoryStream mem = ...)`  in the code, simply because it's IDisposable. It's a counter-productive warning.

Comment: @Jaska: In that case I would pick whichever form of code you prefer and just ignore or suppress the warning. To be honest, unless you're using remoting with a MemoryStream it doesn't matter whether or not you dispose it anyway.

Comment: Ok, i'll just ignore that. This has just bothered me for a long time because i coudn't find anything wrong with the code :)

Answer (score 1):

Reacher-Gilt's link to ms-page led me to the solution, which will make both warnings disappear:

```
        byte[] data = new byte[1000];
        MemoryStream mem = null;
        try
        {
            mem = new MemoryStream(data);
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(mem))
            {
                mem = null; // <-- this line will make both warning go away
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (mem != null)
            {
                mem.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you enter the second using statement, your Bitmap will "consume" the memorystream -- it becomes responsible *for* the memorystream, including its disposal. This is sensible, if you think about your usage: would you expect something else to be accessing `mem` after (or during) you've used it in your Bitmap's constructor? I'd say probably not.

The answer is to consolidate the two using statements together: `using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(new MemoryStream(data)))`. That should take care of the CA warning.

Comment: Generates another warning: Microsoft.Reliability : In method --- object 'new MemoryStream(data)' is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'new MemoryStream(data)' before all references to it are out of scope.